# Customise My zsh Theme

Tags: themes, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Themes and I was wondering how can I make my ➜ start in a new line instead its between the $USER %M and pwd:

```
`function get_pwd() { 
    echo "${PWD/$HOME/~}"
}
local ret_status="%(?:%{$fg_bold[green]%}➜ :%{$fg_bold[red]%}➜ %s)
"PROMPT='%{$fg[white]%}$USER%{$fg[cyan]%}%M ${ret_status}%{$fg_bold[green]%}%p %{$fg[yellow]%}$(get_pwd)%{$fg_bold[blue]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[blue]%} % %{$reset_color%}'
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="❮ %{$fg[red]%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="%{$fg[blue]%}❯ %{$fg[yellow]%}%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN="%{$fg[blue]%}❯"
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I figured it out but I am not sure if its the proper way to do it any suggestions are welcome so basically I put the `local ret_status="%(?:%{$fg_bold[green]%}➜ :%{$fg_bold[red]%}➜ %s)
"PROMPT='%{$fg[white]%}$USER%{$fg[cyan]%}%M %{$fg[yellow]%}$(get_pwd)%{$fg_bold[blue]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[blue]%} 
${ret_status}%{$fg_bold[green]%}%p % %{$reset_color%}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53789/whats-the-newline-symbol-in-zshs-ps1) about ZSH `NEWLINE` options.